# lateral com espaçamento branco quando dá um zoom na página

Tags: html, css

fiz um site usando a minha tela que é 1920x1080, mas quando dou zoom pra 125%, ou acesso o site por um pc de monitor menor, se cria uma faixa branca na lateral do site

segue print de como fica: https://prnt.sc/oa1uexhjUFxH

era pro site se expandir até as extremidades da tela, e nao criar essa lateral branca ...

já tentei mexer em paddings/margins pra ver se saia essa barra, mas nao consigo identificar aonde estou errando

segue o html:

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SobreLoja</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar"> 
        <img src="/imagens/logo.png" alt="logotipo" class="logo">
                <a class="navbar-links" href="#">Buscar Loja</a>
                <a class="navbar-links" href="#">para Proprietários</a>
                <a class="navbar-links" href="#">Para Imobiliárias</a>
                <button onclick="redirect()" class="btn" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket">  Entrar</i></a></button>
    </nav>
</header>

    <div class="container">
        <section class="opcao">
            <p class="container-title">Encontre a loja dos seus sonhos!</p>
            <div id = seletores>
            <select class = "selecao" name="Cidade">
                <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
            </select> <br>    
            <select class = "selecao" name="bairro">
                <option value="0">Bairro (Busque por Bairro)</option>
                <option value="1">Vila Sônia</option>
                <option value="2">Itaim Bibi</option>
                <option value="3">Pinheiros</option>
            </select> <br>
            <select class = "selecao" name="valor">
                <option value="0">Valor (Busque por Valor)</option>
                <option value="1">até R$1.000,00</option>
                <option value="2">R$1.000,00 a R$2.000,00</option>
                <option value="3">R$2.0000,00 a R$3.000,00</option>
                <option value="3">R$3.0000,00 a R$5.000,00</option>
                <option value="3">R$5.0000,00 a R$7.000,00</option>
                <option value="3">R$7.0000,00 a R$9.000,00</option>
                <option value="3">mais de R$10.000,00</option>
            </select> <br>
            <select class = "selecao" name="tamanho">
                <option value="0">Tamanho (Busque por Tamanho)</option>
                <option value="1">até 20m2</option>
                <option value="2">de 20m2 a 50m2</option>
                <option value="3">de 50m2 a 1000m2</option>
                <option value="3">de 100m2 a 200m2</option>
                <option value="3">de 200m2 a 300m2</option>
                <option value="3">de 300m2 a 500m2</option>
                <option value="3">mais de 500m2</option>
            </select> <br>
            <select class = "selecao" name="estabelecimento">
                <option value="0">Estabelecimento (Busque por Estabelecimento)</option>
                <option value="1">Shopping Iguatemi</option>
                <option value="2">Shopping Ibirapuera</option>
                <option value="3">Shopping Morumbi</option>
            </select> <br>
            <select class = "selecao" name="tipo">
                <option value="0">Tipo (Busque por Tipo)</option>
                <option value="1">Lojas</option>
                <option value="2">Quiosques</option>
                <option value="3">Alimentação</option>
                <option value="3">Boxes</option>
            </select> <br>
            <div id = botaoBuscar>
                <input id = buscar type="button" type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="pic"></section>

        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="barra">
        <p class="barra-title">pontos comerciais em shopping centers, centros comerciais, galerias e rua</p>
    </div>

    <section class="cards">

        <div class="card loja">
            <p class="card-title">lojas</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card quiosque">
            <p class="card-title">quiosques</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card food">
            <p class="card-title">Alimentação</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card box">
            <p class="card-title">Boxes</p>
        </div>

    </section>

    <footer>

        <p style="text-decoration:underline; font-size: 26px;">Sobre nós</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Conheça o SobreLoja</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Regiões Atendidas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>

    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

aqui o CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}


.header {
    background-color: rgb(114, 20, 20);
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
}

.logo {
    width: 144px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 85px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-links {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-links:before,
.navbar-links:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar-links:after { 
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
}

.navbar-links:before { 
    right: 0;
    top: -10px;
}

.navbar-links:hover {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-links:hover:after,
.navbar-links:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}


.btn {
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 23px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(78, 16, 16);
    color: white;
}

.btn:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 1s;
}


.opcao {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.container-title {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    
}

#seletores{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.selecao{
    width: 450px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#botaoBuscar{
    text-align: center;
}

#buscar{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: rgb(114, 20, 20);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url(../imagens/main.jpg);
    background-size: cover;

}

.search-btn {
    padding: 13px;
}

.pesquisa input {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.barra {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
}

.barra-title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.cards {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.card {
    width: 23%;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius: 25px;
    
}

.loja {
    background-image: url(/imagens/roupas.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.quiosque {
    background-image: url(/imagens/quiosque.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.food {
    background-image: url(/imagens/food.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.box {
    background-image: url(/imagens/box.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}


.card-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;

}


.welcome-title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
}

.welcome-subtitle {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#email {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}

#password {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}

label {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


footer {
    background-color: rgb(114, 20, 20);
    height: 170px;
    padding: 20px;

}

footer ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

footer ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: no inicio  do css deixe essa definição `*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}` ... para entender mais segui uma referencia https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: **box-sizing** define como a largura e a altura totais do elemento serão dimensionada .